# Methods subscribed via FB.Event.subscribe to comment.create or comment.remove are not triggered

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a partial view in my MVC application where I want to display a Facebook comment box. I also want to save information in my database for each comment that a user posts - yes, I know they're visible on Facebook as well, but I need to save them in the database.

To that end, I wrote this code (NOTES: this is all the code I have in my partial view, I tried to split it to be more readable. Also, the app key is correctly inserted.):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
{
    FB.init({ appId: 'MY_APP_KEY', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); console.log('fb init');
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
        function (response)
        {
            console.log("comment created");
            var commentQuery = FB.Data.query("SELECT text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_fbid='" + response.commentID +
                "' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='" + response.href + "')");
            var userQuery = FB.Data.query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid in (select fromid from {0})", commentQuery);
            FB.Data.waitOn([commentQuery, userQuery], function ()
            {
                var commentRow = commentQuery.value[0];
                var userRow = userQuery.value[0];
                console.log(userRow.name + " (id: " + commentRow.fromid + ") posted the comment: " + commentRow.text);
                trackcomments(response['commentID'], response['href'], 'create', commentRow.text, userRow.name, commentRow.fromid);
            });
        });
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove',
        function (response)
        {
            console.log("comment removed");
            trackcomments(response['commentID'], response['href'], 'remove', null, null, null);
        });
};
(function ()
{
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
    e.async = true; document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ()
    );
```

The trackcomments function:

```
function trackcomments(_commentid, _address, _action,
 _commentMessage, _userName, _userId)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/trackcomments',
        data:
             {
                 commentId: _commentid,
                 pageUrl: _address,
                 actionTaken: _action,
                 userName: _userName,
                 userId: _userId,
                 commentMessage: _commentMessage
             },
        success: function (result)
        {
            console.log("successfully received callback");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And the facebook comments tag, just below the above code:

```
    <fb:comments notify="true" href="<%= Request.Url.ToString() %>" num_posts="3" width="630"></fb:comments>
```

The problem is that every time a comment is posted (or removed), the functions don't trigger. The only console log text I see is "fb init". Obviously, nothing happens on the server either.

I've been scratching my head for the last two days but I can't seem to find the answer - I'd be very grateful to anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should put everything related to FB.[...] functions (FB.init, FB.Event.suscribe, ...) in

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    // Your code
});
```

Otherwise your code will be parsed before the FB js sdk has been fully loaded and you will never really suscribe to your event

Comment: Hmm my bad sorry, no idea what the problem is then.
I had a similar probleme when 2 FB.init where triggered on the same page, the events where not sent to the good instance, but I don't think that it is the cause here...

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure to add the `notify="true"` tag, and if that doesn't work for you, be sure you are using the latest fbComments plugin.  Try adding the `migrated="1"` tag as below, and see if this helps:

```
<fb:comments notify="true" migrated="1"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and just managed to solve it. My issue was that i had 2 different fbAsyncInit registrations. Once i combined them both i started receiving comment notifications.

And the "notify=true" parameter was not necessary to get the comment notification.

**Wrong :**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    // Init and Authenticate
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    // Comment Event Subscribe.
});
```

**Right :**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    // Init and Authenticate
    // Comment Event Subscribe.
});
```